# Required option of the filter deactivates validation in ZF3

Tags: php, validation, filter, zend-framework3

In ZF3 I created a form with two fields: text and url. Only one of them may be filled out by user and at least one must be filled out.

Imagine: one can put the contents of the site or the url of the site. The form may be used to grab certain data from the site or text.

I prepared two validator classes. One for each input. The classes were getting the input value of the other one from context parameter. The StringLength validator was used for both fields.

This worked almost fine but the bad issue was coming when both fields were submitted empty. Then the data did pass the validation while it should no.

At the case of this issue the fields have `required` turned to false.

When I switched them to true both of fields got required but I wanted only one to be required.

So the goal is that when both fields were empty the validation result would get false. Then the only one message should appear. I mean the message  more or less like this: `One of fields must be filled out.` Not the 'required' message.

Here you are the form class and both validator classes.

```
<?php

namespace Application\Filter;

use Application\Form\Test as Form;
use Application\Validator\Text;
use Application\Validator\Url;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class Test extends InputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name' => Form::TEXT,
            'required' => false,
            'validators' => [
                ['name' => Text::class],
            ],
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'name' => Form::URL,
            'required' => false,
            'validators' => [
                ['name' => Url::class],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Application\Validator;

use Zend\Validator\StringLength;
use Zend\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class Text implements ValidatorInterface
{
    protected $stringLength;
    protected $messages = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stringLengthValidator = new StringLength();
    }

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        if (empty($context['url'])) {
            $this->stringLengthValidator->setMin(3);
            $this->stringLengthValidator->setMax(5000);

            if ($this->stringLengthValidator->isValid($value)) {
                return true;
            }
            $this->messages = $this->stringLengthValidator->getMessages();

            return false;
        }
        if (!empty($value)) return false;
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Application\Validator;

use Zend\Validator\StringLength;
use Zend\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class Url implements ValidatorInterface
{
    const ERROR_NOT_ALLOWED_STRING = 'string-not-allowed';
    protected $stringLength;
    protected $messages = [
        self::ERROR_NOT_ALLOWED_STRING => 'Only one of text and url field may by filled.',
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stringLengthValidator = new StringLength();
    }

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        if (empty($context['text'])) {
            $this->stringLengthValidator->setMin(3);
            $this->stringLengthValidator->setMax(500);

            if ($this->stringLengthValidator->isValid($value)) {
                return true;
            }
            $this->messages = $this->stringLengthValidator->getMessages();

            return false;
        }
        if (!empty($value)) return false;
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }
}
```

### Update

I used advises from @Crisp and had to do some correction in the code. Added returns and message handling. The working code is below:

```
<?php

namespace Application\Filter;

use Application\Form\Test as Form;
use Application\Validator\Text;
use Application\Validator\Url;
use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter;

class Test extends InputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name' => Form::TEXT,
            'required' => false,
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'continue_if_empty' => true,
            'validators' => [
                ['name' => Text::class],
            ],
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'name' => Form::URL,
            'required' => false,
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'continue_if_empty' => true,
            'validators' => [
                ['name' => Url::class],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Application\Validator;

use Zend\Validator\StringLength;
use Zend\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class Text implements ValidatorInterface
{
    protected $stringLength;
    protected $messages = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stringLengthValidator = new StringLength();
    }

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        if (empty($context['url'])) {
            if (empty($value)) return false;
            $this->stringLengthValidator->setMin(3);
            $this->stringLengthValidator->setMax(5000);

            if ($this->stringLengthValidator->isValid($value)) {
                return true;
            }
            $this->messages = $this->stringLengthValidator->getMessages();

            return false;
        }
        if (!empty($value)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Application\Validator;

use Zend\Validator\StringLength;
use Zend\Validator\ValidatorInterface;

class Url implements ValidatorInterface
{
    const ERROR_NOT_ALLOWED_STRING = 'string-not-allowed';
    const ERROR_EMPTY_FIELDS = 'empty-fields';
    protected $stringLength;
    protected $messages = [
        self::ERROR_NOT_ALLOWED_STRING => 'Only one of text and url field may be filled out.',
    ];

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->stringLengthValidator = new StringLength();
    }

    public function isValid($value, $context = null)
    {
        if (empty($context['text'])) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                $this->messages = [
                    self::ERROR_EMPTY_FIELDS => 'One of the fields must be filled out.',
                ];
                return false;
            }
            $this->stringLengthValidator->setMin(3);
            $this->stringLengthValidator->setMax(500);

            if ($this->stringLengthValidator->isValid($value)) {
                return true;
            }
            $this->messages = $this->stringLengthValidator->getMessages();
            return false;
        }
        if (!empty($value)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function getMessages()
    {
        return $this->messages;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure your validators always run, even for an empty value, you need to add the `allow_empty` and `continue_if_empty` options to your input specs. Otherwise validation is skipped for any value that isn't `required`.

The following combination should work

```
class Test extends InputFilter
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->add([
            'name' => Form::TEXT,
            'required' => false,
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'continue_if_empty' => true,
            'validators' => [
                ['name' => Text::class],
            ],
        ]);
        $this->add([
            'name' => Form::URL,
            'required' => false,
            'allow_empty' => true,
            'continue_if_empty' => true,
            'validators' => [
                ['name' => Url::class],
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

That combination should ensure your validators are applied when empty values are encountered.

Rob Allen (@akrabat) wrote a useful blog post detailing the combinations which is worth bookmarking [akrabat.com/zend-input-empty-values/](https://akrabat.com/zend-input-empty-values/)